# Copy Dynamically and paste to different excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy data from a closed excel sheet another excel sheet. The code below is working fine as expected. However, I want to dynamically copy all filled rows and columns, instead of having these ranges hard coded in my macro. Can you please help me on this?

```
Dim filename As String
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
Dim src As Workbook
Set src = Workbooks.Open(filename, True, True)
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets(1).Range("A1:BL648").Formula = src.Worksheets(2).Range("A1:BL648").Formula
```

Like I mentioned, the code above is working fine, but I have hard coded both copy and paste ranges. Instead  Ineed those to be made dynamic to copy only filled values from src.worksheets(2) and paste these to worksheets(1).

```
Worksheets(1).Range("A1:BL648").Formula = src.Worksheets(2).Range("A1:BL648").Formula
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. Capture the used range address of the sheet and then paste to the same region.

```
Dim filename As String
filename = Application.GetOpenFilename
Dim src As Workbook
Set src = Workbooks.Open(filename, True, True)


Dim addressText As String
ThisWorkbook.Activate
addressText = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Address
Worksheets(1).Range(addressText).Formula = src.Worksheets(2).Range(addressText).Formula
```